# When is it possible to diagonalize a metric tensor with a coordinate transformation?

Tags: general-relativity, differential-geometry, metric-tensor, coordinate-systems

The question is a mathematical one, but I believe more likely to find here interested people, as it is relevant for GR. The problem arose for Kerr space-time and Boyer-Lindquist coordinates, where the metric tensor is not diagonal ($g_{t\phi}\ne0$). Of course I mean to diagonalize $g_{\mu\nu}$ at least in an open subset, not in a single point.

A simple accounting of unknowns and equations gives 4 unknown functions (the 4 coordinate functions) against 6 equations (for the vanishing of 6 out-of-diagonal components of metric tensor). So I would guess the general answer is no: some integrability conditions must be met in order diagonalization to be possible. But I'm not able to go further.

Comment: Somewhat related, Carroll discusses Riemann normal coordinates in hgis lecture notes (page 49-51 in https://arxiv.org/abs/gr-qc/9712019), i.e. the question of putting the metric in Minkowski form. He sketches a proof and cites the textbook by Schutz, so maybe you can start from there and generalise the argument.